# change color of an element on click in pure JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code:

```
<div> item1 </div>
<div> item2 </div>
<div> item3 </div>

var x = document.querySelectorAll('div');

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  x[i].addEventListener("click", function (){
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
      if(x[i].style.color === ""){
        x[i].style.color = "red"
      } else {
        x[i].style.color = ""
      }
    }
 });
}
```

I would like to change color on click each item, instead I get color changed on all of them. How can I change the color and only on the clicked element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looping through all of the `<div>`s in your handler. A simpler way is this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (x[i] !== this) {
    x[i].style.color = "";
  }
}
if (this.style.color === "red") {
  this.style.color = "";
} else {
  this.style.color = "red"
}
```

In this case, `this` refers to the element being clicked.

Comment: You can use ternary operator: `this.style.color = this.style.color === "" ? "red" : ""`

Comment: @Tushar That is less clear, especially for a new coder.

Comment: Thank you, but what if I want to make only one element  selected red?

Comment: @Alex What do you mean? If you put this in the event handler, then it should only changed the clicked element.

Comment: I mean how can I prevent other elements from being selected red, while one of them is checked red?
Similar to radio buttons but only with color

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through all the divs and appending listeners to them, add only 1 listener to the window and if it's a div then change its color.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const target = event.target; // what you clicked on
    if(target.tagName !== 'DIV') {
        return; // not a <div>, stop the function
    }

    const color = target.style.color;
    target.style.color = color? '' : 'red'; // color is set then clear it, otherwise set to 'red'
});
```

Or:

```
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div');
Array.from(divs).forEach(div => {
    div.addEventListener('click', changeColor);
});

function changeColor() {
    let color = this.style.color;
    this.style.color = color? '' : 'red';
}
```

Also, you need to wrap the Javascript code in a `<script> /* JS here */ </script>` tag.